# Managed Property is null defined in Managed Bean

Tags: jsf-2

The Managed Property value is null even though the setter method is added in the Managed Bean.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@XmlRootElement(name = "name")
public class Name{
 private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
      this.firstName= firstName;
    }
}

@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ViewScoped
public class Person{

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{name}")
    private Name name;

     public String displayName(){       
       name.getFirstName(); //name is null
     }
    public void setName(Name name){
      this.name= name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is code `name.getFirstName` located? This is really useless code here.

Comment: Did you specify a certain beanname for your managedbean "Name"? Maybe you named it "nameBean"? Is your setter defines like: "setName(Name ..)"?

Comment: There is no beanname defined for managedBean Name.

Comment: Is the *setName* method being called? If so, is the provided *name* Object null?

Comment: displayName() method is called on the xhtml page. The setter method for Name is never called. The Name class is in a different project. Can this be the reason for null value?

Comment: @BalusC: Name class is in a different project. This project does not have Faces-config defined. What all files are needed to identify the managed bean in this project?

Comment: If `setName` never gets called, then that's the problem. That other project needs a `faces-config.xml` as well. You don't need the `eager` attribute I guess, check out what it means!